# From what age should I expect the child to pick up her toys which she scattered while playing?

Tags: discipline, age-appropriate, toys

At what age should this be started?

How to go about it such that the child doesn't feel bored?

Comment: My mom started this pretty much immediately. It was a rule in our house that toys have to be put away before moving to a new toy. However, she didn't make us clean up alone; she cleaned up with us (meaning she did most of it, whereas we picked up a couple toys).

Comment: @Justin, sounds like an answer to me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From toddlerhood onwards.

Do it together - initially you'll be doing almost all of it and the balance should gradually shift over the years as they get older.

At first, give out copious praise even for small acts of tidying up.

Make it a race.

Have something desirable / positive to do next, once tidying up is done. Don't let them do the fun thing until they've helped with tidying up, even if it's just one symbolic thing that they tidy eg car into box.

Sing the "Tidy Up Time" song together while you're doing it (or your local equivalent that they might get to know from nursery / kindergarten/ etc).

To the tune of Frere Jacques:
*Tidy up time, tidy up time

Toys away, toys away

Everybody helping, everybody helping

Toys away, toys away*
(Repeat until tidy).

Comment: +1 for "race".  We use that to make many boring tasks more fun.

Comment: Yes, making it a race or a game makes it easier. We often have toys put away in bins or baskets and make a tossing game out of clean up.

Comment: @CreationEdge a note about tossing - my nieces picked up a bad habit of throwing things at people after seeing their mother toss some toys into the bin.

Comment: @DanHenderson My boy picked that up after being old enough to throw things. It's hard to avoid seeing people throw stuff, as it's a basic human skill and game. (Throwing rocks, throwing spears, throwing balls, throwing discs). I'd rather show them how to toss things productively, and discipline otherwise.

Comment: @CreationEdge yes, I suppose it would depend on whether they've already learned to throw things or not. In our case, the issue was that the things they saw their mom throw weren't things that should be thrown as part of normal play. Balls and soft things, sure, but small, hard plastic toys no, because skin and walls.

Comment: @DanHenderson We had the same issue. We taught our guy hard vs. soft (or squishie) very early on, just to keep him from throwing the wrong kinds of things!